# Pulling Default WordPress Category Name in Widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the default category name on my site to a WordPress widget.  Is there a way to pull this string (not the ID) automatically?  I only have one category so i thought it would be easy, but none of the following are working:

- `<?php bloginfo('category'); ?>`
- `<?php get_category(); ?>`
- `<?php get_the_category(); ?>`
- `<?php get_category([0]); ?>`
- `<?php get_the_category([0]); ?>`
- `<?php get_category([0]->cat_name); ?>`
- `<?php get_the_category([0]->cat_name); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_category(); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_the_category(); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_category([0]); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_the_category([0]); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_category([0]->cat_name); ?>`
- `<?php echo get_the_category([0]->cat_name); ?>`

Any help is appreciated...

UPDATE: 08/01/13 - Amal pushed me onto the right path.  I ended up using the following and it worked perfectly...

- `<?php echo get_cat_name(get_option('default_category'));?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$category = get_category(get_option('default_category'));
```